# shieldSplitter collapse event not firing?

Tags: shieldui

I'm using the shieldSplitter and the collapse event is not working. This is what I'm doing.  I see no alert.  Any idea?

```
           jQuery("#container").shieldSplitter(
           { 
                    collapse: function (event) 
                    {
                        alert("Pane");
                    },
                    orientation: 'horizontal',
                    panes: [ { size: '65%' }, { size: '35%' } ]
           });
```

Comment: I'm simply trying to trigger an event when the pane splitter is moved/resized. The "resize" event doesn't raise either.

Answer (score 1):

The splitter is not initialized correctly. Here is an examplary code of splitter with 3 panes:

```html
var splitter1 = $("#pane1").shieldSplitter({
            barSize: 3,
   orientation: "horizontal",
   events: {
    collapse: function (e) {
     alert("collapse");
    }
   },
   panes: [
    { size: '200px', collapsible: true, collapsed: true, min: '100px', max: '260px' }, 
    { size: '100px' },
    { collapsible: true }
   ]
  });
```